# Pandas | Fillna(ffill) in a grouped dataframe doesn't fill

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultIndex dataframe and am trying to fill down a value, `MAX_PTS_YR`, such that the value of `MAX_PTS_YR` in year `t+1` equals `MAX_PTS_YR` in `t`.

So: `MAX_PTS_YR` in `2016` should equal `116`.

Using `nth`, I found `MAX_PTS` for the prior year:

```
DF['MAX_PTS_YR'] = DF.groupby(by=['Affiliation','Year'],as_index=False)['PtsYr'].nth(-1)


Affiliation mkid        Year    PtsYr  MAX_PTS_YR
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2015    96.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2015    96.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2015    106.0   NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2015    116.0   116.0
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    10.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    10.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    20.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    20.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    30.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    40.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    50.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    50.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    52.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    62.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    62.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    82.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    94.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    94.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    94.0    NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    104.0   NaN
MVPAFL0003  10176228    2016    114.0   114.0
```

And I thought I could `fillna` down on that `Affiliation` group:

```
DF.groupby(by=['Affiliation'],as_index=False)['MAX_PTS_AFFIL'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

But when I do that, no `NaN` values are filled in.

**Any ideas**?

Comment: I think the problem is with the `inplace` parameter. You are working on a copy so it actually modifies the copy. Try `DF['MAX_PTS_AFFIL'] = DF.groupby(by=['Affiliation'],as_index=False)['MAX_PTS_AFFIL'].fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't work; I get `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Answer (score 1):

```
# get just the series you are filling to simplify things
s1 = df.set_index(['Affiliation', 'Year']).MAX_PTS_YR

# groupby to get the max per group
mx = s1.groupby(level=[0, 1]).max()

# shift your year index by one year
mx.index.set_levels(mx.index.levels[1] + 1, 1, inplace=True)

# fill in missing bits
s1.fillna(mx)
```

---

```
Affiliation  Year
MVPAFL0003   2015      NaN
             2015      NaN
             2015      NaN
             2015    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    116.0
             2016    114.0
Name: MAX_PTS_YR, dtype: float64
```

---

Now assign to df

```
df.MAX_PTS_YR = (s1.fillna(mx).values)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one last question: how do I set the last value in a given year to be consistent, given the above example? So, `MAX_PTS_YR` in line 20 to be equal to `116` instead of `114`, and equal to `NaN` on line 2?

Comment: @user791411 that is inconsistent with what you asked for. You should include a filled out dataframe that represents what you want.

Comment: my apologies. What I'm looking for is to have all row values of `MAX_PTS_YR` for a given year be equal to the max of `PtsYr` in the prior year, grouped by `Affiliation` and `mkid`. Therefore, I'm hoping there's a way to set the last value of a given year to be consistent (so `116` for every `MAX_PTS_YR` value for `2016` for a given `Affiliation`). I thought `fillNa` was the way to go, but if there's a better way to reach my objective. So, using the above image, [see this picture](http://imgur.com/a/bbjJN) (apologies, don't think I can put the dataframe I'd like to into a comment).

Comment: I ran out of space above; if there's a better way to reach my objective, I would sincerely appreciate the suggestion!!

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only column with null data, you can just do the operation on the whole dataframe:

```
DF.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Note that will return floats even if you originally entered the number of points as integers. This is because the NaN's are technically floats and they force the type of the whole column. To get ints (which is probably what you want unless you can have partial points) do this:

```
DF['MAX_PTS_YR'].astype('int64', inplace=True)
```

Maybe you'd like to do that to the PTS column too.